# React-native Android: tag <Image> no visible image when load from DB or http

Tags: react-native

My problem is when load images from DB or https by the way

```
<Image style={{width: 25,height: 25}} source={{ uri: 'http://192.168.202.36:81/api/images/12.jpeg' }} />
```

(192.168.202.36: localIp, size capacity of image: 100-300 KB), it is not visible in android emulation device. I try logged on to the screen and saw the image link was there. I think my program has not loaded yet in time to render, it's one program of asynch???

Comment: If you directly visit that image url in your emulator's browser, can you see it?

Answer (score 0):

Images can be slightly tricky in react-native. But there are several things you can do to troubleshoot them.

- make sure your source is valid:
  in your case make sure it's

  ```
  source={{uri:http://192.168.202.36.81/api/images/12.jpeg}}
  ```
- make sure you can load the image at that url from your actual phone's browser (it could be your phone is not on the same wifi as your laptop/server)
- Make sure your image is actually visible on the screen. Sometimes I like to add a border to an element if i'm not sure it's actually displaying, or add height/width just to be sure.

These steps can help when troubleshooting images in React Native. But always be quick to check the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html) if you ever run into problems.

Comment: I have get image success from browser with link which logged on to the screen, but i can't load image on android emulation device. Or the problem here is size capacity of image???

Comment: You can always test with a publicly available image such as an image from google images or similar. That way you can figure out if your problem is network (talking to your server from your device), or if it is actually styled / configured incorrectly from the react-native side.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your URI has been set correctly
2. Set a manual width and height for your image

An example is like this

`<Image source={{uri: 'uri_address'}} style={{width: 200, height: 200}} />`

Comment: I was add style for this but still not visible image